# Font inconsistency in amsart

Tags: titles

I am using the `amsart` document class with the `kpfonts` package.

The problem I face is that the font for the number of sub-sections is different from the one of the title. I would like everything to be bold.

[image: Example]

I tried `\def\@secnumfont{\bfseries}` but it lead to new inconsistencies within the appendix.

[image: Appendix]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{kpfonts}

\begin{document}
    \subsection{Lorem ipsum dolor}
    \appendix
    \section{Sit amet}
\end{document}
```

Comment: No, with `amsart` the section number is not boldface.

Comment: I never mentioned sections

Comment: “section” in generic sense. Can you please add a minimal example of code?

Comment: In this case, the fact that the numbers are not in bold is precisely the problem. I've added the example even though it's not very interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following patch to `\@seccntformat` - the macro responsible for setting the `sec`tional unit `c`ou`nt`er `format` - inserts a formatting parameter that can override section-specific formatting for the number. Specifically, I've defined `\subsectionnumfont` as `\bfseries`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{kpfonts,etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\subsectionnumfont}{\bfseries}
\patchcmd{\@seccntformat}% <cmd>
  {\@secnumfont}% <search>
  {\@secnumfont
   \csname #1numfont\endcsname}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}

\appendix

\section{An appendix}
\subsection{A sub-appendix}

\end{document}
```

Any non-existent sectional formatting results in `\relax`.